# Node Database Query not working;

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm

Im completely new to NodeJS coding, so to make it more challenging to myself I'm also trying to use ORM via "[node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)" (unless someone could suggest an easier orm framework?)

I'm using an Ubuntu Server, which also has MySQL, Apache & Tomcat installed on it - so i want the Node app to listen on port 3000; (Apache is on Port 80, & Tomcat is on Port 8080).

I've installed the MySQL Driver + ORM modules, & they're situated correctly within the 'node_modules' folder - which is a subfolder of my project.
MySQL is setup simply with the username: "user" & the password: "password"

When I run the App I get the error message:
"Connection error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"

Oh - and the App is simply trying to write a record to the Database 'Test', and if its successful, it simply returns the message 'Success' to the browser.

Here's my code so far;

```
var http = require('http');
var orm = require('orm');
var message;

orm.connect('mysql://user:password@localhost/Test', function(err, db) {
  if (err) return console.error('Connection error: ' + err);

    var Test = db.define("test", {
        User      : String,
        Num   : Number,
        Address   : String,
        Phone   : Number,
        State   : String
      });
      var newRecord = {};
        newRecord.User = 'Username';
        newRecord.Num = Math.random();
        newRecord.Address = '10 Idiot St, Somewhere';
        newRecord.Phone = 12345678;
        newRecord.State = 'VIC';
        orm.create(newRecord, function(err, results) {
          if (err) return console.console.error('DBError: ' + err);
        });
        message = 'Success';
  });

  var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Response: ' + message);
  }).listen(3000, "192.168.0.127");

  console.log('Server running at http://192.168.0.127:3000/');
```

Comment: Do you have that port 3306 open or blocked by a firewall perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The ECONNREFUSED Error generally occured under the following conditions:

The packet was sent out but returned with errornous results (Could potentially be firewall, not having the service running on not being on the correct port. Network failures are unlikely to cause this error becuase It indictated that a "connection" was already made but only after, refused).

Considering you are running on localhost, some of this might be unapplicable.

However, the line at the end of the HTTP server code where you listen on specific network adapter might not be necessary?

Are you sure your service is running?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue... but then found a new issue with my ORM code;

While MySQL is on the same Server as Apache, Tomcat, Node, PHP etc, I forgot that i configured MySQL to listen on its IP (instead of listening on LocalHost), as i wanted it to be able to respond to requests from other machines;

So my code needed to look like this;

```
orm.connect('mysql://user:password@192.168.0.127/Test', function(err, db)
```

now my code is just throwing an error on this line, saying that "create" isn't a method of ORM:

```
orm.create(newRecord, function(err, results)
```

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't the SQL issue, it should also be noted that in my code:

```
 orm.create(newRecord, function(err, results)
```

should actually be:

```
Test.create(newRecord, function(err, results)
```

stupid rookie mistake, i was trying to use the connection object to add a record.